# Plausible source of superpowers

Tags: super-powers

So in a book that I'm writing. I have a world with superheroes in it, and my main character needs a way to gain telekinetics, at the same time that there are two other kids with him who don't gain the same powers. It can't knock any of them out.

And the setting is a fire in a school lab. I need some way that some crazy **chemical substance** reacts in a way that it starts a fire and, **without injuring him**, give him telekinetics specifically.

It needs to sound plausible and follow at least a bit of logic and laws of physics. You can bend physics but I prefer that you don't break them.

For context, here is the principle behind telekinetics in my world: A super-enhanced brain that uses energy incredibly efficiently and emits unique brain waves that can wrap around an object and move it based on the way that the person wants the object to move, but the focus used scales to the total mass of objects they are trying to move.

To be incredibly clear. I need the source of his powers to be somehow an unknown **chemical substance** interacting with his brain specifically, enhancing it to be able to emit such brain waves that allow for telekinetics

Comment: Keep in mind, I already have a superhero character with wings growing out of his back.

Comment: This is too opinion-based. It's a fishing-for-ideas question and those don't work well on this site. A radioactive spider isn't plausible, but there have been millions of happy fans since, which means almost anything will do and they'll all be equally valid (which is against the rules, see [help/dont-ask]). I'm willing to retract my vote if you can explain how you will select a best answer.

Comment: There is no plausible science-based way to have telekinesis, therefore there can be no plausible science-based way to gain it.

Comment: Wanting to find a way for telekinesis to be plausible logically and with the laws of physics is commendable. Your principle behind telekinesis doesn't fit in physics as we know it. It doesn't bend physical law, it breaks them and rebuilds in a completely different form. This isn't unreasonable if you making a fictional world with alternative science. In fact, it would be interesting challenge to start with your TK principle as a given, & work out how super-powers can be acquired.

Comment: Yeah the second clause of how it works does break physics.

Comment: I want to know how this is opinion-based

Comment: I have seen way more "opinion-based" questions than this one here on worldbuilding

Answer (score 1):

You could take influence from the movie Phenomenon with John Travolta (spoilers ahead) long story short he develops telekinesis and it is revealed that it is due to a brain tumour.

You could have an explosion where a small amount of a radioactive element which was used for school experiments goes off not far from the children and the one child which is more sensitive to radiation is the only one affected.
This then leads to them developing a tumour which changes their brain chemistry and with some hokum hand-wavium this leads to their telekinesis powers.

It sounds simple but other than a radioactive element there isn't much an explosion could do to the brain to change it, other than knocking the person out and hand-wavium makes them wake up with powers and you would be surprised how many people buy in to this tumour/superpowers theory, so it could be quite believable to audiences.

Comment: Good Idea but brain tumors are usually lethal, and I don't want my main character on a death clock.

Comment: Ok, then skip the tumour and say the radiation changed their neural composition.

Comment: I will keep it in mind. But for now, I'm going to wait and see if anyone else comes up with something

Comment: Thats a good idea to wait, I just thought it was worth mentioning the idea. I would add that the next step could involve the brain sending out a particular wavelength of energy which can affect the objects that need to be moved but this would involve a serious amount of electricity you will need to handwave, ideas like this are featured in meditation theories which you might find to be good inspiration for this power.

Comment: @Firestryke There can be benign brain tumours. Then your character can live as long as plot allows.

Answer (score 1):

We know very little about the brain and how it works. Stories I've read before play off of the idea that there's a part of the brain with a dormant function that can be reawakened by specific chemical or medical procedures.

So try this: There is (in your story) part of the brain that *everyone naturally has* that can emit this type of telekinetic waves, but has fallen out of use in humans and *started to lose that function* as centuries/millennia passed.

When your main character breathes in a large amount of the fumes of whatever chemical reaction starts the fire, **it has the effect of awakening that dormant brain function.** He won't know how to use it right away, of course, but he starts noticing its effects and tries to learn how to use it over time (which could be a big part of your story; you want some sort of growth and development of the skill to happen).

The people with him don't get it because he breathed in more of the chemicals, either being right over the experiment when the critical reaction occurs or maybe trying to stop it from spreading (while the others run) and getting an overdose that way.

Yes, there's a bit of handwavium, but all superhero backstories need something like that; I sure haven't seen any hard-science stories of superheroes getting powers. At least, to me, it makes sense and sounds like something that could plausibly be the case.

Comment: Thanks! Im going to modify this a bit, but otherwise, it will work great for my story!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the superpowers method created by Wildbow for *Worm*. In my opinion, it's a very "realistic" way to grant reality-bending powers which would otherwise be completely impossible to obtain (there is no possible combo of high school lab chemicals that grants telekinesis). Now, MAJOR SPOILERS for *Worm*, but here is how superpowers work in that setting:

There is a creature, an Alien known as an "Entity", which resembles a massive fleshy-crystalline space whale. It has the mass of hundreds of planets and consists of cells, called "Shards". Entities and the Shards they're made of are essentially super-complex biological supercomputers with the (technological) capability to do things like create wormholes or portals to other alternative realities and emulate superpowers, but unfortunately, like computers, they are not creative. To counteract this, they form parasitic relationships with people who are.

Typically, this occurs in a "Cycle". An Entity will find a planet inhabited by sapients and then shuffle its mass into empty parallel dimensions. Then, the entity shuffles remote links to individual shards across the race of sapients in the form of small, anomalous, organs in their brains. Through this organ, which is actually an anchor for the extra-dimensional Shard and direct brain-interface for the human, a Shard can grant a superpower that the human can direct with their brain. For example, a shard could be built in a manner that lets it project hard-light constructs around the anchor and the human would use their creativity to form these into things like shields, armor, weapons, whatever, while the Shard collects that delicious creativity data.

Unfortunately, the relationship between Shard and host isn't a good thing. Shards desire data above all else and it doesn't really bother them when their host dies. This means that Shards employ several strategies to get their hosts to use their powers and gather data. For example, people with powers have a "conflict drive" which means they get antsy and irritable if they don't use their powers and get into fights. Secondarily, Shards only grant powers during "[Trigger Events](https://worm.fandom.com/wiki/Trigger_Event)" which are moments of extreme psychological distress. By doing so, the Shards ensure that their hosts have difficulty moving past their trauma and filters for people who have "interesting" lives, which further increases the likelihood that the host will use their power in new and creative ways.

Granting your protagonist a power is easy in this scenario:

1. Protagonist and his friends are in the chem lab when something goes wrong. Maybe a fire breaks out
2. Protagonists friends are trapped and if the protagonist ran to get help, the friends would surely die.
3. The protagonist already has had people (close family) die and can't stand the idea of losing someone else close
4. Among the stress of the situation, they wish "If I could just reach that fire extinguisher on the far wall" and an inactive Shard notices this extreme state of psychological distress and grants telekinesis.

Comment: Not from an unknown chemical substance